# Excel weeknum conditional average

Tags: excel, average, week-number

### Date Number Weeknum

> 4-Jan-96  0.094288    2
>
> 5-Jan-96  0.092872    2
>
> 8-Jan-96  0.090431    2
>
> 9-Jan-96  0.153586    2
>
> 10-Jan-96 0.029758    3
>
> 11-Jan-96 0.052083    3
>
> 12-Jan-96 0.042797    3
>
> 15-Jan-96 0.047949    3
>
> 16-Jan-96 0.053029    3
>
> 17-Jan-96 0.051588    4
>
> 18-Jan-96 0.036755    4
>
> 19-Jan-96 0.043954    4
>
> 22-Jan-96 0.067316    4

I want the average number where weeknum is a certain value -edit(and year is a certain value) without averaging for every week by hand.  Does anyone know whether there is an averageif/if/other condition that can do this? Weeknum doesn't always contain 5 consecutive values because holidays are preventing that.

Comment: Do you want this as a formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  =AVERAGEIF(C1:C13;2;B1:B13)
```

Column **C** is the week number column.
Argument #2 is the week number you're interested in.
Column **B** is the column with the values to average.

Comment: wow thanks this works but i forgot to mention that multiple years are involved and that after week 53 the counter resets to one. Do you know a solution for that? Would be much appreciated

Comment: Come up with an idea, used =concatenate(weeknum(),year()) and removed duplicates from the data tab in an extra column. If any smoother method exists feel free to respond.

Answer (score 1):

Column A: date
Column B: value for the date
Column C: Weeknum for the date
Column E: Weeknumbers (1..52)
Column F: `=SUMIF(C1:C10;E1;B1:B10)/COUNTIF(C1:C10;E1)`

Comment: Confirmed working thanks although the averageif methods looks shorter